# Пробую создать таблицу в MySQL,выдает ошибку

Tags: mysql, table

Пишет как я понимаю что не выбрана база данных. Затем я добавляю команду для использования тестовой базы, но программа уже придирается к синтаксису. Несколько раз перепроверила вроде все правильно. Кавычки использовала те которые над буквой Ё. Неужели дело в них? И еще в строке "серия и номер паспорта" DEFAULT мне нужно было ввести `0-0`, я пробовала набрать NULL-NULL но программа не приняла.КАК БЫТЬ?

```
CREATE TABLE `Сотрудники`
 (`Идентификатор сотрудника` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Фамилия` VARCHAR(30),
  `Имя` VARCHAR(20),
  `Отчество` VARCHAR(35),
 `Дата рождения` DATE,
 `Серия и номер паспорта` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Идентификатор сотрудника`))
 ENGINE InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8
 USE test;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приводите данные текстом, а не картинкой, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ваш код

Comment: CREATE TABLE `Сотрудники`
        -> (`Идентификатор сотрудника` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        -> `Фамилия` VARCHAR(30),
        ->  `Имя` VARCHAR(20),
        ->  `Отчество` VARCHAR(35),
        -> `Дата рождения` DATE,
        -> `Серия и номер паспорта` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
        -> PRIMARY KEY (`Идентификатор сотрудника`))
        -> ENGINE InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8
        -> USE test;

Comment: после выбора базы все должно работать - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69eff2/1

Answer (score 2):

Сначала

```
USE test;
```

и только потом

```
CREATE TABLE `Сотрудники` (
    `Идентификатор сотрудника` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Фамилия` VARCHAR(30),
    `Имя` VARCHAR(20),
    `Отчество` VARCHAR(35),
    `Дата рождения` DATE,
    `Серия и номер паспорта` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Идентификатор сотрудника`)
) ENGINE InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

PS. Структурка так себе. Особенно серия и номер паспорта в одном поле...

Answer (score 1):

Кириллицей разве можно называть таблицу? Я не такой маньяк, чтобы в коде использовать русский конечно, но если он там работает, то перед CREATE TABLE нужно просто написать

```
use <имя бд>;
```

Comment: Кириллицей никто не пользуется. Все давно в Unicode работают.

Comment: Я все прекрасно понимаю, но это не моя воля.